What is the best way to calculate the partial charge?
I'm looking for advice on calculating atomic charges, particularly when dealing with metal atoms in a structure. I'm currently using the RESP method with the following Gaussian input:
#p B3LYP/gen pseudo=read SCF=tight Pop=(mkuff) iop(6/33=2) iop(6/42=6) iop(6/50=1)

My complex includes a ruthenium atom. I've noticed that the ESP and RESP charges for the metal are quite low, around 0.56, while the Mulliken charge is higher at 1.45. From what I understand, Mulliken charges are highly sensitive to the choice of functional and basis set. However, the literature suggests that the atomic charge for Ru in a similar complex is around 1.19.
Which value should I use for my .mol2 file in order to proceed with Molecular Dynamics simulations?

There is no a best way to calculate the charges. That's why there are several schemes:

Mulliken population analysis [1,2,3,4]
Natural population analysis (NPA) [5]
Breneman-Wiberg (BW) model [6]
Merz-Kollman-Singh (MKS) electrostatic potential derived
charges [7,8]
Bader partition scheme [9,10,11,12]
Voronoi partition scheme [13,14]
Hirshfeld partition scheme [15]

Personally, I recommend avoiding Mulliken as they are highly dependent on the basis set used. Instead, the Hirshfeld partition scheme it is proven to be highly
insensitive to the choice of the basis set.
Edit: almost all that charge scheme are implemented in the MultWFN package.

Thanks for answering. What do you think about Restrained Electrostatic Potential? Do you the think the difference in Atomic charge can effect the simulation?

I have never worked with Restrained Electrostatic Potential. And yes, atomic charges will definitely affect all other simulations that depend on electrostatic interactions.
